# Boot firmware on router from RAM without flashing?

Tags: firmware

I have this router [DIR 605L](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=72849) and I would like to test some firmwares that I have but without actually flashing device. Basicly Im in Bootloader CLI

```
<RealTek>?
----------------- COMMAND MODE HELP ------------------
HELP (?)                                    : Print this help message
SIG: SIG <type><sig>
SIGR: Display signature and flag
LOADADDR: <Load Address>
J: Jump to <TargetAddress>
FLR: FLR <dst><src><length>
FLW <dst_ROM_offset><src_RAM_addr><length_Byte> <SPI cnt#>: Write offset-data to SPI from RAM
MDIOR:  MDIOR <phyid> <reg>
MDIOW:  MDIOW <phyid> <reg> <data>
PHYR: PHYR <PHYID><reg>
PHYW: PHYW <PHYID><reg><data>
PORT1: port 1 patch for FT2
<RealTek>
```

Does anyone know how to copy firmware to RAM and boot it using  CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/bootloader/realtek) is explanation what mean what on RealTek CLI,
and to flash firmware here is what I did

```
Press 'Esc' key at boot to interrupt
Enter 'IPCONFIG'
Upload image by TFTP
        > $ atftp -p -l fw.bin 192.168.1.6
```